# Kicking off multiple actions from an Effect WITHOUT hitting a service

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to create an effect that kicks off multiple actions but does not make a call to a service.

1. is using an effect the best way to accomplish this?
2. if so, how do I write the effect without calling a service (all the examples I can find have actions kicking off after the service is called)

this is what I have so far although i'm pretty sure it's wrong.

```
filterList$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ListActions.filterList),
    mergeMap(() => {
        return [new ListActions.loadList(),
                    new ListActions.filterListBySearchString(),
                    new ListActions.filterListByCategory(),
                    new ListActions.filterListByHealthBenefit()                    
    })
))
```

Comment: seems legit for me, we did that in my prev. project, action result was actually a list of other  actions and that's fine

Comment: Your solution is not wrong. The way to solve this problem is already like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code works and is AFAIK the only way to do it.
That being said, it's a bad practice - for more info see:

- https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/avoid-dispatching-multiple-actions-sequentially.md
- https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/no-multiple-actions-in-effects.md

Answer (score 0):

*all the examples I can find have actions kicking off after the service is called)*

There is a reason for this - effects are for handling side effects (like calling a service). Your effect does not have a side effect - therefore it is not required at all.

I assume the multiple actions you dispatch here each relate to an effect of their own ie `ListActions.filterListBySearchString` => `filterListBySearchStringEffect` or similar.

If this is the case, just change the 'trigger' action for each of these effects to be `ListActions.filterList` and remove the effect you have here altogether.